# Is there any way to print JUnit or Hamcrest diff result in non-test method?

Tags: java, json, junit, diff, hamcrest

in a non-test method I want to compare to JSON format `String`s, and get output like what we can see from unit test's assert functions or `git diff`. Can we somehow print out JUnit or Hamcrest diff result in non-test method?

Comment: There is no need to use JUnit or Hamcrest for that (using test libraries in production code is not a good idea). There are more generic text diff solutions available, but library recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: what about in integration test?